# How to start Application object using android? Help me to understand this concept by adding some keys (Codes)

Tags: android

```
package com.example.activitylifecycle;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.util.Log;
public class MyApplication extends Application {
static final String TAG = "MyApplication";
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
@Override
public void onCreate() {
super.onCreate();
Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
}
@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
super.onLowMemory();
Log.d(TAG, "onLowMemory");
}
@Override
public void onTerminate() {
super.onTerminate();
Log.d(TAG, "onTerminate");
}
```

Help me to understand this concept by adding some keys (Codes).
 I am new to android, What are the purpose of using Application objects?

Comment: What? Dont understand you question... What do you want to know?

Comment: When to use Application Object in android? i have the example code above.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn Android i have to recommend the google documentation:
there is also a description of the lifecycle and the application itself
http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

and her is also a tutorial to extends Application

http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/